# Buttons assigned to elements on Adapter for listview dont works well

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview

i have one list of "comentario" elements, this is the comentario class:

```
public class Comentario {
private String comentarista;
private String comentario;
private Button boton;
public Comentario(String nombre, String comentario){
    this.comentario=comentario;
    this.comentarista= nombre;
}
public String getComentarista() {
    return comentarista;
}
public void setComentarista(String comentarista) {
    this.comentarista = comentarista;
}
public String getComentario() {
    return comentario;
}
public void setComentario(String comentario) {
    this.comentario = comentario;
}
public Button getBoton() {
    return boton;
}
public void setBoton(Button boton) {
    this.boton = boton;
}
```

}

The "comentario"´s listview have his adapter that have buttons for answer each comment to his owner. When the user press on the button "Responder", another activity must starts to answer it ("ActivityRespuestaComentario"). However, when i press the button, "ActivityRespuestaComentario", this activity receives any name from adapter who calls it through the bundle and the answer to the comment is for any of owners of the comments in the list.

This is the "ActivityRespuestaComentario" activity:

```
package com.example.pestanasholacampus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ActivityRespuestaComentario extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actividad_respuestaenperfil);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    Bundle bundle= intent.getExtras();
    String destinatario;
    if(bundle!=null){
        destinatario= bundle.getString("NombreDestinatario");
        System.out.println("El destinatario es:"+ destinatario);
    }
    Button botonEnviarRespuesta= (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonEnviaRespuestaComentario);
    botonEnviarRespuesta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Aqui debemos añadir el comentario a la lista de comentarios del destinatario en la base de datos.
            System.out.println("Comentario añadido.");
            finish();

        }
    });


}
```

This is the adapter which have the onclicklistener for each button of the list view:

```
package com.example.pestanasholacampus;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") public class ComentarioenPerfilAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
protected Activity activity;
protected ArrayList<Comentario> comentarios;
Context mcontext;
TextView nombre;

public ComentarioenPerfilAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Comentario> comentarios, Context context){
    this.activity= activity;
    this.comentarios= comentarios;
    this.mcontext= context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return comentarios.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return comentarios.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
@Override
public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
    View v= inf.inflate(R.layout.comentariolistperfil,null);
    //Asociar el layout de la lista que hemos creado.
    //Definimos un objeto a partir del array, vamos a cargar el contenido
    //de ese objeto en el view de la lista.
    Comentario comentario= comentarios.get(position);
    //Cargamos el nombre del comentarista.
    nombre= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nombreComentarista);
    nombre.setText(comentario.getComentarista());
    //Cargamos el comentario
    TextView coment= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.comentario);
    coment.setText(comentario.getComentario());
    //Cargamos el boton
    Button boton= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.botonResponder);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Boton responder comentario pulsado");
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,ActivityRespuestaComentario.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);  
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("NombreDestinatario", nombre.getText());
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

I did the"Comentario" class thinking on each element of the listview without meditate over the buttons and the problem could be there but i dont know where i have to put the onclicklistener for each element answer to his owner correctly.

I think you have all of you need to help me, if it is not, pleas tell me and i will post it.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below method

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt works. I will add this change on the post code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on widgets of listview then you will have to mention in in your adapter class where you defined them using your xml class of adapter class.

Comment: I dont understand you. The buttons are atributes of "comentario"class and they are defined on the adapter and on the xml element of the list.

Comment: Where are you getting problem?

Comment: The problem is that when i press on the "Responder" button, this answers to the first person of the list and no to the person whose button i have pressed.

Comment: Because you're not passing the position of that button of listview. You'll have to pass the position onClick.

Comment: I have thought that when you press the button of one of the elements of the listview this button answered to that element. I pass to the onclicklistener the name of the element which i want  to answer but im not doing well. I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is add tags to the buttons. Each button have his tag which contains an object you need to obtain the correct data.
button.addTag(amigo); in the adapter
You have to set buttons with android:onclick="handler" and your handler have to stay in the class where you calls the adapter.
This handler will take the tag as getTag over one instance.